# Symfony2 best way of removing business logic from controller and correct usage of model

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller

I'm in searching of the best way of removing business logic from controller and correct usage of model(and maybe services).

Some details below.

Actually, my project is more complicated, but as example I will use Simple Blog application.
I have created my application (Simple Blog) in next steps:

1. created bundle
2. generated entities(Topic, Post, Comment)
3. generated controller for each entity, using doctrine:generate:crud
4. installed FOSUserBundle and generated User entity

So, I have all needed methods and forms in my controllers. But now I have some troubles:

1. Admin need to be able see all topics and posts, when simple User can only see
   topic and posts where he is owner.

Currently there are indexAction, that return **findAll** common for any user. As solution, I can check in action, if ROLE_USER or ADMIN and return **find** result for each condition. But this variant keep some logic at action.

I also can generate action for each role, but what happened if roles amount will increase?

**What is the best way to solve this problem with result for each role?**

2. I need to edit some parameters before saving.

For example, I have some scheduler, where I create date in some steps, using [features of DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).
Before saving I need to do some calculations with date.
I can do it in controller using service or simple $request->params edit.

**What is the best way to edit some $request parameters before saving?**

My questions I have marked with bold.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What I would do is to create a query which fetches the topics. Afterwards I would have a method argument which specifies if the query should select only the topics for a certain user or all topics. Something like this should do the work in your `TopicRepository`:

   ```
   public function findTopics($userId = false)
   {
       $query =  $this->createQueryBuilder('topic');

       if($userId) {
           $query->join('topic.user', 'user')
               ->where('user.id = :user_id')
               ->setParameter(':user_id', $userId)
           ;
       }

       return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
   }
   ```

   So, whenever you need to get the topics only by a user, you would pass a `$userId` to the method and it would return the results only for that user. In your controller you'd have something similar to this code (Symfony 2.6+):

   ```
   $authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

   if($authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
       $results = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository('TopicRepository')->findTopics();
   } else {
       $results = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository('TopicRepository')->findTopics($this->getUser()->getId());
   }
   ```
2. You can try using [Doctrine Events](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks) and create a `PreUpdate` depending on your case. See the documentation for more information. If you have a `TopicFormType`, you could also try the [form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html).
3. You are not supposed to "edit" a `$request`, which is why you can't directly do that. You can, however, retrieve a value, save it as a `$variable` and then do whatever you want with it. You can always create a new `Request` if you really need it. Could you be more specific what you want to do here and why is this necessary?

Comment: Well, I have form, where I can customize period of processing some action.
So, as result I can get DateTime("first sat of July 2008"),
or DateTime("+2 days " + $now()) etc.
I need to calculate current date from received notations before saving.
So I need change $request->datetime into concrete date.

Comment: The `Request` is rather "read-only" representation of the client's request so you can't do much from the controller if you don't initialize a new `Request` manually. I'm pretty sure that's not considered as best practice in symfony. If you need to make calculations on your time period you should either use Doctrine Events, Form Events or do it inside your controller.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have understood this. And last question: is it true way to checking roles in the repository? your first example is quite good, but incomplete, because I need get different result for each role. (for example, I have 4 roles.)

Comment: I believe so. You would only have to make an if statement which checks if the user has a role `ROLE_ADMIN`, if not you would pass the `$userId` to your repository. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer!

Comment: Glad I could help! Поздрави от България! :)